# error when building 32-bit linux kernel on 64-bit linux host

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to build 32-bit linux kernel 2.6.9 on a 64-bit linux host with 2.6.9 (same version).  Did some google search and tried the following:

step 1) make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS=-m32 menuconfig

step 2) make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS=-m32

Step 1 was okay. But step 2 got the following errors.  What did I do wrong?

```
make ARCH=i386 CFLAGS=-m32 
< snip >
In file included from include/asm/smp.h:18,
                 from include/linux/smp.h:17,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:23,
                 from arch/i386/kernel/asm-offsets.c:7:
include/asm/mpspec.h:6:25: mach_mpspec.h: No such file or directory
In file included from include/asm/smp.h:18,
                 from include/linux/smp.h:17,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:23,
                 from arch/i386/kernel/asm-offsets.c:7:
include/asm/mpspec.h:8: error: `MAX_MP_BUSSES' undeclared here (not in a function)
include/asm/mpspec.h:22: error: `MAX_IRQ_SOURCES' undeclared here (not in a function)
In file included from include/linux/smp.h:17,
                 from include/linux/sched.h:23,
                 from arch/i386/kernel/asm-offsets.c:7:
include/asm/smp.h:72:26: mach_apicdef.h: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [arch/i386/kernel/asm-offsets.s] Error 1
make: *** [arch/i386/kernel/asm-offsets.s] Error 2
```

Comment: Do you have the kernel-devel package installed?

Answer (score 1):

The `make ARCH=i386` should be sufficient assuming you have everything required by the build installed on the machine. I use this almost daily to build i386 on a "ubuntu 12.04".

If you have built a 64-bit kernel previously, you should have everything, and it's possible that you need to "make clean" or even "make mrproper" [save your .config somewhere safe for the latter], because I know for example asm_offsets.s will be different between 32 and 64-bit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  What do you mean by "everything required by the build installed on the machine" ?  To clarify, I did not install any extra / special builds tools.  The gcc and make are all native.  I think they should work because the host linux is at the same version (2.6.9 x86_64).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what I installed to build the kernel, I think the sources and the gcc compiler. Can you build the 64-bit version? If so, you should be able to build the 32-bit version. Of course, 2.6.9 is an ANCIENT version - 2.6.38 is the latest 2.6 kernel, and the 3.x kernel is up to 3.8 by now (I'm running 3.7rc5+ on my machine that I'm typing this on).

Comment: yes. I can build 64-bit version successfully.  And I made some progress. After adding:  -Iinclude/asm/mach-default into CFLAGS, the above errors are gone. But I hit a new error from AS: arch/i386/kernel/entry.S:145: Error: suffix or operands invalid for `pushf'
I suspect that somehow AS still trying to use x86_64.  I even added ASFLAGS='-march=i386 --32'  but did not help.

Comment: You shouldn't have to muck around with those types of settings. Have you tried simply compiling a "hello world" in 32-bit, to make sure tht 32-bit builds work at all - on my Fedora machine, I can't build 32-bit code [I haven't REALLY needed to, so I haven't tried to find out why it doesn't work].

Comment: Building a program like "hellow world" is successful. Actually all user-space 32-bit builds are okay on this host.  Only have problems when building 32-bit kernel.

Comment: By the way, via another discussion,  I changed to use "AFLAGS" instead of "ASFLAGS" and making more progress now.  Still not done though ;-)